# Why am I not able to up-vote any posts?

Tags: support, questions, upvotes

I can't up-vote any questions and answers. A few days ago it worked fine. What happened?

I observe error in console.

```
error : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

and I am using Google Chrome browser.

Comment: What happens when you try to vote? Do you get any error messages? Please try to provide more information.

Comment: Do you see scripts failing to load in your error console? Did you try hard-refresh-bypass-cache?

Comment: when i click on up arrow it count my vote and suddenly my vote's gone means count is decrement.

Comment: @ABPrime - can you see any errors in your JS console?

Comment: console shows this : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: @ABPrime, are you running AdBlock or similar?

Comment: @ABPrime - Does that error show up before or after you try to vote? Please add all of this information to your original question - it will help identify the problem.

Comment: You should try to report bugs in the same manner as you would want to receive them for your projects... "It doesn't work" is not a bug report... It's just a complaint with no other information...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes i am using adblock pro plugins in chrome browser.

Comment: @ABPrime, chances are that's the problem. You will probably have to whitelist the site.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I tried in firefox and it works. but how to solve problem on chrome because i need that plugins.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i add stackoverflow into whitelist still problem in vote-up . so what should i try.

Comment: @ABPrime, clear your cache, refresh the page, keep an eye on your error console to see if the same message comes back, double-check the domain you have whitelisted if that's the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have something on your browser blocking one of the required elements.

The fact that the error message is:

```
error : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

is clear indication that this is the case.

Turn off any ad blockers you have (at least temporarily) to see if they're blocking the resources. If they are then you'll need to add the necessary domains to your whitelist.